# How many different isomers of $C_3 H_4 Cl_2 F_2$ exist?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, chemistry

I was on my high school chemistry class when I came across this problem, which, I think, belongs to group theory. The problem is that it is not possible to label the carbons as reflection should not be counted twice. (That is, 3,3-dichloro-2,2-difluoropropane is called 1,1-dichloro-2,2-difluoropropane)
(The carbon chain in the case of propane is fixed.)
And, how to solve the general problem of counting different isomers of 
$\require{mhchem}\ce{C_{n}H_{x}Cl_{y}F_{2n +2-x-y}}$ ?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate the group structure you're talking about, for those who don't favor chemistry that much ?

Comment: @Emre : $C$ has valence $4$, $H : 1$ , $Cl : 1$, $F:1$, and the problem is that a chain of $C$ doesn't have to be linear (see [isopentane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopentane) or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclohexane). then we must check if the $C-C$ bounds are all simple (no double bounds as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene or even [Benzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzene) ), then we have to describe all the possible $C-C-\ldots$ skeletons (by taking in account the symmetries : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(chemistry) ) and finally place the $H,Cl,F$

Comment: if you forget the chirality, this is purely graph theory

Comment: and in the case of propane ($n=3$) everything is easy : choose the number of $F,Cl,H$ for each $C$, and take in account the chirality of the $C-C(HClF)$  groups (two ways for arranging such groups spatially), and take in account the symmetry of the $C-C-C$ chain

Comment: So if you were to take propane $(C_3 H_8)$ and replace 2 with fluorines and 2 with chlorines, isn't it possible with casework.

Comment: I only found 31 isomers....

Answer (score 2):

$\rm C_3H_4Cl_2F_2$ is an alkane.   There are no multiple bonds or rings to worry about.   Further only one skeleton is permissible here: a three carbon chain.   The end two carbons have three groups attached, the middle carbon but two.   The carbon-carbon bonds can rotate freely so we only need worry about possible carbon chirality, and any mirror symmetry.

Noting that we have the same number of chlorine and fluorine atoms simplifies things as we can just check to see if exchanging them produces an isomer; but watch out for interaction with other symmetries.

$\begin{array}{ccc:ccc} &&& \text{middle C} & \text{end C} & X\leftrightarrow Y  \\ (\;)&(X)&(XY_2)& \times 2 & & \times 2\\ (\;)&(X_2)&(Y_2)&&&\times 2\\ (\;)&(XY)&(XY)&\times 2&\times 2&\div 2 & \text{the X-Y interchange cancels isometry}\\ (X)&(\;)&(XY_2)&&&\times 2\\ (X)&(X)&(Y_2)&\times 2&&\times 2\\ (X)&(Y)&(XY)&\times 2&\times 2&\times 2\\ (X)&(XY)&(Y)& \times 2\\ (X)&(Y_2)&(X)&&&\times 2 \\ (X_2)&(\;)&(Y_2)& \\ (XY)&(\;)&(XY) & \times 4&&\div 2 \end{array}$

I count <s>27</s>29 isomers, but may well have missed others.

The general case gets much *more* complex.

Comment: So after all it's just a case bash?(ie brute force enumeration)

Comment: Are you not missing the (XY) () (XY) case?

Comment: (it is an halogeno-alkane : a chloro,fluoro-alkane, or a chlorofluorocarbon (CFC) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorofluorocarbon used as refrigerants, and responsible of the ozone depletion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_depletion )

Comment: @gilleain Indeed.  I'm rusty on this.

Answer (score 1):

Odd, I get <s>30</s> <s>33</s> 32 (last one is [a meso isomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meso_compound)) stereoisomers from 16 constitutional isomers. Like so (red asterisks indicate a stereocenter) :

[image]

Sadly, the method to get this count was 'brute force enumeration' (in fact, a variant of the canonical path augmentation method of McKay for multigraphs).

The stereocenters were deterined by eyeballing the structures and thinking about it - so they may well be wrong!

**Edit** : Indeed, I missed the chiral centers on FC(Cl)CC(F)Cl. As to the more general question, I'm not sure how to 'extend' the series in some natural way.

For example, here are some counts of constitutional isomers for various similar formulae:

### Formula|Count

- C4H5Cl3F2 86
- C4H6Cl2F2 59
- C5H6Cl3F3 632

All found using the same method.

Comment: I don't get how you get different chirality for other groups than $C-C-(HClF)$ as I wrote

Comment: @user1952009 I don't really understand what a "C-C-(HClF)" group is. In any case, the chiral centers marked with an * in the diagram all have four different groups attached. eg the bottom left image has C(H)(CHF2)(Cl)(CH2Cl) to abuse SMILES notation a bit.

Comment: Also I notice that the last one is a meso isomer! Gah. So the count is actually more like 32 isomers.

Comment: you are right, sorry I got it, I forgot the case $G_1-C(XY)-G_2$ which is chiral  whenever $G_1 \ne G_2, X \ne Y$  (and I meant $C-C(HClF)$)

Comment: and the last one $CHClFH-CH_2-CHClF$ there are only two conformations, because of the symmetry

Comment: @user1952009 You're quite right, thankyou. I've edited that in.